# Reduce the margin of a uilabel with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a problem and is that in the uilabel on the right is in blue because i have a margin to the right so that you always see me on the right side of the device, but the uilabel "Introduction" marked in gray on some devices it is overlaid above and i wanted to in some way that when you pass this the uilabel suits without arriving to overcome above another as for example by reducing its text ..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` on the `UILabel` to make it adjust its font size to fit in the available space.

EDIT

I would put the following constraints:

**Left Label**

1. Leading space to superview
2. Fixed width
3. Trailing space to Center Label
4. Top space to superview

**Center Label**

5. Leading space to Left Label
6. Trailing space to Right Label
7. Top space to superview

**Right Label**

8. Trailing space to superview
9. Fixed width
10. Leading space to Center Label
11. Top space to superview

And finally, `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` for the Center Label if you like.

Comment: As you can see in the picture, in my graphical interface the uilabel has reserved space of leftovers the problem is that depending on the device this size you will need to be adjusted and i do not really need to adjust the content simply to be for example Diagnose ... cut at the end, also thanks for your response http://es.tinypic.com/r/11177rd/8

Comment: This would work if my size reserved for the uilabel is less than the text, but the space for the uilabel is greater that the text entered the problem is that the text is overlaid on top of the other uilabel , if you're looking at the image that I will give you my storyboard you'll see the layout

Comment: Because this friend , the idea was to put a constraint (Horizontal spacing) between the 2 and take away uilabels fixed width to the first and then put a truncate tail , thank you also for your answers!

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Comment: But if you don't know how closes the question , thanks